# Use jQuery serializeObject to make array of multiple radio boxes

Tags: jquery, json, serialization

While i tried to get json data from html inputs i found this thread:
[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

The serializeObject function does most of the things I need, there is only one thing I haven't got done yet

I have 4 characters and to each of them the user can assign 0 to 3 points

So the json I get is

```
{"charakter1":"0","charakter2":"2","charakter3":"3","charakter4":"1"}
```

But i would like save this information as array, so what i want is

```
{"charakter":[0,2,3,1]}
```

How do i have to change the name of the radio buttons to get this array?

I created a jsfiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3028/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using arrays for the variables, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="charakter[2]" value="0"/>0
<input type="radio" name="charakter[2]" value="1" checked />1
<input type="radio" name="charakter[2]" value="2"/>2
<input type="radio" name="charakter[2]" value="3"/>3<br/>

<input type="radio" name="charakter[3]" value="0"/>0
<input type="radio" name="charakter[3]" value="1" checked />1
<input type="radio" name="charakter[3]" value="2"/>2
<input type="radio" name="charakter[3]" value="3"/>3<br/>
```

Results in this:

```
{"charakter":["0","2","3","1"]}
```

jFiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3029/